# Best Roles and Capability on a site with review features using a front end custom post

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I'm working on a Movie Blog site, I'll be having a movie review for site members and planning to create/install plugin that can create a front-end post/edit using a custom post type for that reviews. I'm also planning on creating custom **roles and capabilities** for my members that will register on my site. My question is what's the best Role and Capabilities to use for this kind of membership? He's the list of what I'm planning for the users.

- Can edit their profile.
- Can write/edit their own review(via custom post type)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My fist suggestion to this type question is to use [**Justin Tadlock's Members Plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). It should handle what you are asking, and it's easy to set up. It has several pre-defined roles and capabilities that will probably cover what you need. If not, check out the forums and doc's for how to customize it even further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i don't want to be plugin dependent, but this one is a good starting point to reference the capability that i will need to create.